# Source attachment does not contain the source for the file view.class

Tags: android

I am new to android and making a simple application of a temperature converter. i had placed 2 text views and a button on  the screen. i just wanted to saw that when i press  the button an event comes or not when i run the application no event came after pressing the button so i put it in debug mode then it gives a message

**Source Not Found:Source attachment does not contain the source for the file view.class**

*Here is my code:*

**Activity_main.Xml**

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/red"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
        android:onClick="onclick"
        android:text="@string/Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="@string/Large_Text"
        android:textStyle="italic" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="@string/Large_Text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Strings.Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Converter</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="Button">Convert</string>
   <string name="Large_Text">Deg C</string>
   <string name="Large_Text1">Deg F</string>
   <color name="red">#D3D3D3</color>
</resources>
```

**Main_activity.java**

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**I have created a classs1.java**

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Classs1 extends Activity{

public void onclick(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText(4);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

U did not call event listener to ur view

```
public class Classs1 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ur_button_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                             TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                             t.setText(4);
            }
          });
}
```

#### Edit:

*Error :* `Source Not Found:Source attachment does not contain the source for the file view.class`

Did u add `classs1.java` in your `manifest` file Plz check that too.

Comment: btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() can this be replaced by this btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: @ Sam it is still giving the same message when i put it in debug mode